# Definition and derivation of conditional expectation/probability

Tags: probability, measure-theory, probability-theory, expectation, conditional-expectation

I read quite a few books introducing the notion of conditional probabilities/expectation by putting a formula out there coming from what they call "intuition".

Can someone provide me a good measure theoretic derivation of how to find the conditional expectation or probability of a random variable ? Or even a link or something.

Basically knowing the basic in measure theory,let $(\Omega, Z,P)$ be a probability space.

How do you derive finally that any function g s.t :

\begin{align}
\int_A YdP = \int_A gdP_{|G}
\end{align}

is the expectation of $Y$ knowing $G$. And also how do we go from there to find :
\begin{align}
P(A|B) = \frac{P(A,B)}{P(B)}
\end{align}

Any explanation/links/books is appreciated !!

Comment: On cond exp or $\sigma$-algebras: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/192179 https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2048219 https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/37497 https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1273287/ https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2711361 https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/375994 https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/26733 https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/77757

Answer (score 0):

Try reading chapter 9 of Probability with Martingales by Williams (especially Section 9.6 - Agreement with Traditional Usage) and/or chapter 23 of Probability Essentials by Jacod and Protter.